# dynamically require/import different component modules in React Native depending on build config

Tags: reactjs, react-native, babeljs, babel-plugin

I'm working on a React Native project where we will need to build two different flavours of the app, which mostly the same but vary in a few small features. I wanted to see if there was a way to do this through babel somehow, by having different files named similarly for each build and triggering differetn builds by setting and environment variable. This would be similar to the way that React Native does for having custom js files for iOS and Android like this:

```
my-component.android.js
my-component.ios.js
```

so my different build flavours would look like this:

```
my-component.flavourA.js
my-component.flavourB.js
```

or even

```
my-component.flavourA.android.js
my-component.flavourB.android.js
my-component.flavourA.ios.js
my-component.flavourB.ios.js
```

I am trying to find a way of using babel to change the require() function (and import statements) such that the correct files are resolved from a simple require call of:

```
require('./my-component');
```

depending on which *FLAVOUR* environment variable is set. Or:

```
import * from './my-component';
```

I have looked at trying to use a combination of `babel-plugin-module-resolver`, `babel-plugin-replace-require` and `babel-preprocessor` but I'm not able to work out if this even possible without writing my own babel plugin.

Is there an easier way of achieving this that I am missing?

Comment: Did you find any useful solution?

Comment: @MarioMurrent can't remember why I wanted to do this now, it was 5 years ago! I'm sure it's moved on quite a lot now. Ask ChatGPT.